# Converting multiple bitmap to byteArray issue

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap

I have 5 image bitmaps. Which has to convert into byteArray. But while doing using below code it gets struct for sometime. Please help me to be out on this.

```
fun bitmapToString(var bitmap:Bitmap):String{
 val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream)
    val byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()
    return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT)
}
```

and from my class i used below code with new Thread

```
Thread(Runnable{
hmImageBase64[0] = CommonUtils.bitmapToString(resized)
 hmImageBase64[1] = CommonUtils.bitmapToString(resized1)
hmImageBase64[2] = CommonUtils.bitmapToString(resized2)
.
.
.
hmImageBase64[6] = CommonUtils.bitmapToString(resized6)

})
```

Please let me know if anything done by me is wrong. Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: " below code it gets struct for sometime" ?? Please explain what is happening.

Comment: Here Bitmap converting into base64 string. For a single image conversion it takes around 3-5 seconds. So same for 6 images UI gets struct until total conversion. So how to use this in background.

Answer (score 0):

Use asyntask for this don't run the all hmImageBase64[0],1,2... at once. create a queue or in post-execute. 
Start 2nd after first completion and same for others too.

First :

```
Thread(Runnable{
 hmImageBase64[0] = CommonUtils.bitmapToString(resized)
})
```

Second :

```
Thread(Runnable{ 
 hmImageBase64[1] = CommonUtils.bitmapToString(resized2)
})
```

call second after first gets completed and like this all one-after another.